# Change the background image of a div depending on which link is selected in the navigation

Tags: php, javascript, css

i'd like to change the background image of a div depending on wich link is selected in my navigation!

exemple : 
let's say I have a menu item called :

```
#nav li.menu-item-59
```

when the link is selected it changes to

```
#nav li.menu-item-59.selected a
```

I'd like that whenever one of the menu item is selected the background image of the div footer change to a different file...

I've read some articles about sibling operators but can't seem to make it work and I'm not sure it is the best way to go ..
can anyone help?
thanks ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using JS to add the class of `selected` to the menu. At the same time you're adding that, also add the the menu item name to the footer. something like:

```
var menuName = $(this).attr('id');
$('.footer').addClass(menuName);
```

Then in your css for the footer, add the class to the end of the element:

```
.footer.menu-item-59 {
  // background goes here
}
```

based on your fiddle below, try:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){   
  for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++)
    if($(window).scrollTop() +5 >= sections[i].top &&
    $(window).scrollTop() <= sections[i].bottom){
      sections[i].link.addClass('selected')
      .siblings().removeClass('selected');
      var selection = 'selected' + i; // new stuff starts here
      $('footer #flag').removeAttr('class');
      $('footer #flag').addClass(selection);
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm sounds good.. I tried a couple things but don't have it working yet.. here's the js code of my wordpress template that trigger the selected class.. it's a one page website so you'll see the scroll function that trigger the selected state of the navigation :

Comment: Based on that code, can you see the footer at all times? if you add `console.log(sections[i]);` right after  `.siblings().removeClass('selected');` what do you get? can you link to your page?

Comment: sure here is the link : http://www.philippesavard.com/sandbox/folks/

you see the little flag on the right bottom corner ? I have to change the picture so that the fly gets lower when you scroll down the page.. ;) I'll try what you suggested right away!

Comment: waah! so close! ok so how I would style it in the css then to change the flag ? #flag.menu-item-59{background-image:url :....}

Comment: #flag.selected1 { // your stuff here }, #flag.selected2 etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about sibling operators but this might work...

save all the images in one place.
give all links the same class. for this example ive used 'yourmenuclass'.
then query the document and listen for which one has been clicked.
then in the switch statement to assign a different image, depending on which one has been clicked.

```
    function init() {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.yourmenuclass'), function (el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', change);
    });

    function change() {

        if (this.id == 'firstlink') {
            var back = document.getElementById("footername");
            back.style.backgroundImage =" url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Ferns02.jpg/220px-Ferns02.jpg')";
        }
        if (this.id == 'secondlink') {
            var back = document.getElementById("footername");
            back.style.backgroundImage ="url('http://www.dailyshame.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/badger.jpg')";
        }

    }
}


onload = init;
```

if you are using simple  anchors then this may not work, but should be fine for buttons or image inputs.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamMartin121/drHec/)

Comment: hmm ok it's a bit complicated to edit at that level since my site is in wordpress and the navigation menu is hard to edit but I'll give it a shot! thanks

Comment: Ahh I see. No.problem! Good luck! :-)